# Query Build doctrine Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have 2 entity (Rule and analysisRule)( association one to many)

I try to make a query that counts the number of idAnalyseRule that have an idAnalyse pass as a parameter in the function

example:

I pass idRule = 15 as a parameter, the query will count all IdAnalysisRules that have an idAnalysis = 15

I do not know how it works but I try it like that

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $expr = $qb->expr();
        $qb->andWhere(
            $expr->eq('p.analyse', ':analyse')
        )
        ->setParameter('analyse', $analyse);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

this is the manager

```
    /**
         * @param $analyse
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function errorsAnalyseRule(Analyse $analyse){

            return $this->repository->totalErrors($analyse);
        }
```

this is controller

```
     /**
         *
         * Get a totalError by idAnalyse.
         * @param Analyse $analyse
         * @param AnalyseRuleManager $analyseRuleManager
         * @return ApiResponse
         *
         * @SWG\Parameter(name="id", in="path", type="integer", description="Supplier Id"))
         * @SWG\Response(response=200, description="Returns the nbErrors")
         *
         * @Rest\Get("analyses/{id}", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
         */
        public function getTotalErrorsAction(Analyse $analyse, AnalyseRuleManager $analyseRuleManager)
        {
            return new ApiResponse(['nbErrors' => $analyseRuleManager->errorsAnalyseRule($analyse)]);
        }
```

I am in a state of blockage for 3 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with an inner join. In the repository of analysisRule you have to add the function that makes the query and returns the count:

```
public function countAnalysisRule(Rule $rule)
{
    return $this-createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('count(a)')
        ->innerJoin('a.Rule', 'rule')
        ->where('rule.id = :rule')
        ->setParameter('rule', $rule->getId())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

}
```

Don't forget ofcourse to add a use of the Rule class.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html

You should use:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select($qb->expr()->count('p.id'))
   ->from('App:AnalyseRule','p')
   ->where('p.analyse', ':analyse')
   ->setParameter('analyse', $analyse);
$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

where $analyse = 15 in your case !

If you are under 2.6 for doctrine prefer:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(p.id)')
   ->from('App:AnalyseRule','p')
   ->where('p.analyse', ':analyse')
   ->setParameter('analyse', $analyse);
$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```